# Trouble in Launching XAMPP in ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xampp

When I'm trying to launch XAMPP control panel, In the 'Manage Servers' section is is shown that 'Apache Web Server' is Stopped and it does not start. when l run the command line it says that another server is running. So how to find and stop that already running server.

**TERMINAL:**

> Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.1-0...
>
> XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
>
> XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
>
> XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be You are having another instance of apache2 running on your system, so first stop it, run following command and then restart xampp:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop